# Bootstrap Snippet "Buttons minus and plus in input " will not move to right

Tags: html

Input group does not move to the right and stay formatted correctly

```
<div>
    <span id="input-group" class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 20px;">
    </span>
    <class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" 
data-field="quant[2]">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number" 
value="10" min="1" max="100">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" 
data-field="quant[2]">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> use **direction** propirty to change float for all elements

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div style="direction:rtl;">
    <span id="input-group" class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 20px;">
    </span>
    <class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" 
    data-field="quant[2]">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number" 
    value="10" min="1" max="100">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" 
    data-field="quant[2]">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: The Minus & Plus moved but the data field did not?

Comment: try this css code

`
button, input {
    float: right;
}
`

Comment: I should have said.... Minus Button, QTY, Plus Button in a row and not stacked on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12">


<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="pull-right" style="direction:rtl;">
    <span id="input-group"  style="margin-right: 20px;">
    </span>
    <class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" 
    data-field="quant[2]">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is image that is you need ??]